# How do I retrieve timezone code from a Ruby Timezone object?

Tags: ruby, timezone, tzinfo

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 with gems timezone 0.3.1 and tzinfo 0.3.38.
I'm looking to retrieve the current timezone code for a timezone, e.g. 'EST' for 'America/New_York' right now, or 'EDT' in the summer.
I've found nothing in the documentation, yet when I dump the object with the following code:

```
ptz = Timezone::Zone.new :zone => 'America/New_York'
hash = {}
ptz.instance_variables.each do |var|
    hash[var.to_s.tr('@','')] = ptz.instance_variable_get var
end
puts hash.to_json
```

there is an array of 267 "rules", each a hash where "name" contains the value I am looking.
Does anyone know how I should determine which rule is current, so I can retrieve the name value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York').period_for_utc(Time.now).abbreviation` gives you the abbr. for the time provided.

Comment: Thanks!  This approach will allow me to work with historical dates in the data store.

Answer (score 1):

```
  require 'tzinfo'
  tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York')
  tz.strftime("%Z")
  => "EST"
```